# How to get public port number of TcpListener?

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, tcpclient, tcplistener

I'm trying directly connect (using TCP) two devices that are behind routers implementing NAT. As I see, routers are translating port number of my devices, so port 13000 (port where my app is listening for incoming TCP connections) on my computer will have completly different value as seen publicly. In order to connect two devices, I need to know what the listener's "public port number" is.

I've created "rendezvous server" which is available publicly. Firstly, I've created TCP connection between client A and server. Server extracted port number and passed it to other clients so they could try to connect to client A. But I realized, that when I create new Tcp connection with server, my app creates new port from which it sends packets. So server extracts public port of newly created port used just for connection to that server and not public port of my listener.

So I'm trying to solve it other way. The idea is: I'm sending UDP packets with source port set to port of TcpListener. This way, theoretically, server could extract from incoming message public port of TcpListener (by getting source port from UDP datagram) and pass it to other devices in my network.

```
// client side
public void AdvertiseListener(IPAddress address, int port, Guid localDeviceId)
{
    UdpClient client = new UdpClient(ListenerPort); // changing datagram source to port of my TcpListener
    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(address, port);

    _logger.LogInformation($"Advertising Tcp port to server at {address.MapToIPv4().ToString()}:{port}");

    byte[] data = localDeviceId.ToByteArray();
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {
        client.Send(data, data.Length, remoteEP);
    }
}


// server side
public void AdvertisementsHandler()
{
    AdvertisementListener = new UdpClient(ListenerPort);

    AdvertisementListener.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(HandleAdverticement), null);
}


private void HandleAdverticement(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    IPEndPoint senderIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(0, 0); // source address of incoming datagram
    var receivedData = AdvertisementListener.EndReceive(ar, ref senderIpEndPoint);

    [...]

    _logger.LogInformation($"ADVERTICEMENT RECEIVED, port is {senderIpEndPoint.Port}");

    try
    {
        AdvertisementListener.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(HandleAdverticement), null);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Advertiser failed");
    }

}
```

The problem is: my server receives not translated number for some reason. `senderIpEndPoint` in `HandleAdverticement` equals 13000 which is my private port number. It seems like my router, ironically, leaves port as it is this time. Do you have any ideas of what can I change to solve my problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use port forwarding on your router?

Comment: @PatrickMcvay yes, I want my app to work on networks where I don't have access to router settings.

Comment: I'm sure you have thought of this, but have you tried using sockets instead of UdpClient? documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/listening-with-sockets

Answer (score 0):

Your `TcpListener` doesn't have a public port number. If a router is using NAT to  change your source port number along the way, your application will not know about it. This is why port-forwarding is required when you want to make a service available to the public.

What you might be looking for is what is known as [TCP hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching). But in most cases that still requires you to have a public third-party public service that can let the two locations exchange their public endpoint information.

Alternatively [Universal Plug and Play (UPnP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) might allow you to request the router to port-forward automatically. But this is not something I have worked with myself.